# Getting a role based on a localized role name

Tags: user-roles

I use the following code to get the Administrator role

```
$admin = get_role('administrator');
```

This works fine, but on a different WordPress language setup, this code breaks. For example, in French it should be

```
$admin = get_role('adminstrateur');
```

Any cross-language solution?

Comment: Interesting question. +1 I never noticed this (using german lang installations), but maybe you have/had some role manager, membership or capability editor plugins installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but maybe:

```
$admin = get_role( __( 'administrator' ) );
```

If you're trying to make sure that WP translates the string for a specific locale, `__()` will return the translated string.  So if `get_role('administrator')` works and on a French setup `get_role('administrateur')` would work, then the above code snippet should do what you need.

Comment: but per my knowledge you need to provide the translation file, no?

Comment: Calling `__( 'some text' )` is identical to calling `__( 'some text', 'default' )` ... it will use WP's default text domain.

Comment: I guess it would be (uppercase 1st char) `Administrator`.

Comment: It works and not. I'm not really sure but it fixes the bug. Anyway, I'm rewriting the roles class in the future, so that's a temp hack.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is `translate_user_role()`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/translate_user_role/

```
$admin = get_role( 'administrator' );
$localized_name = translate_user_role( $admin->name );
```